# Class's attribute are placed together in dia uml creator

Tags: uml, dia

I downloaded dia uml creator from its site.I have created simple class but why some my text attribute are placed together?
I am using `dia.exe 0.97.2` version

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the names of your attributes. It looks like some of them (e.g. `EdgeBarDoc`) start with CR and/or LF or another character that doesn't make much sense in this context.

I guess maybe it never occurred to the program author that somebody may place a line ending inside an attribute; so the program doesn't check against it, accepts it "as is" and happily wraps any affected line (at the very beginning in your case).